# What is the main plot of One Point O / Paranoia 1.0?

Tags: plot-explanation, one-point-o

2004 movie [One Point O](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317042/) shows the young main character increasingly distressed by a disturbing environment, worrying neighbors, and brutal events occurring to them.

I felt there could be some hints scattered in the movie about what causes these issues, or even explanations, but I could not understand well enough the dialogs or actions depicted in the film to make a conclusive opinion.

This fuzziness is probably on purpose, but what is the main plot of the movie?

Is it somehow a commentary about how new technologies affect human behaviors and relationships?

Is there a simpler story to understand here?